# How to run iphone /ipad App in ipad simulator by selecting target device family=iphone/ipad?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, ios4, ios-simulator

I am creating app for both  iPhone and iPad

For that I am selecting:

**ProjectInfo -> Build -> Deployment ->Target Device Family -> iPhone/iPad**

When I run my App, it always opens in iPhone simulator only.

So using the same setting, How can I Open my app in iPad simulator?

Please Help and Suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch active executable platform here:
Project->Set Active Executable-> (choose iPhone or iPad)
or
from Overview drop-down control (placed in toolbar)